# Initializing state with generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

edit:

### IMPORTANT

As @jcalz mentions, the example as is, it is wrong, since if there is any `State` defined on child component, than the initialization is wrong.

As a way to ignore it, it is possible to use `as` key as @sychd mention, but remember **this example is actually an error**

---

I'm struggling with initializing state with typescript

So I have a component that has variable state, i.e. the component has state, but the children can also define (extra) state.

This brings the problem of trying to initialise the parent state with only the part that it knows of.

This piece of code can explain the issue

```
interface Default {
  something: boolean
}

class A<State> {
  state: State & Default = {
    something: false
  }
}
```

check: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Default%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20something%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%3CState%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20State%20%26%20Default%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20something%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

So above we see that `state` complains about that `Default` type is not assignable to `Default & State`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a valid error to me; you haven't initialized `state` to a valid `State & Default`.  When in the code does it get set properly?

Comment: I was attempting to set it partially, but it makes sense if I initialise it partially it is not a valid object of that type.

Answer (score 1):

As about your code - the trick is `as  State & Default` because TS see `{something: false}` as some object. But

```
class A<State> {
  state: State & Default = {
    something: false
  } as  State & Default;
}
```

will be ok.
Also, probably it will suit your needs, you can try extandable generics:

```
interface Default {
  something: boolean
}
interface State extends Default {
  something: boolean,
}

class A<T extends Default> {
  state: T = {
    something: false
  } as T;
}
```

Comment: Using a type assertion (`as`) is only a good idea if the developer knows that the assertion is or will be valid, since it relaxes the compiler's type checking.  The code as it stands looks like it should be an error, unless @mloureiro adds more information about how `state` will be properly initialized.

Comment: @jcalz, yep. But declaration object with params(as in code snippet) will not suit any type with same fields (except `state: {something: boolean} = {something: false}`), so explicit cast is required. Otherwise, he can pass set param via constructor or via setter, so explicit cast can (and should) be avoided